# HarpJS: layout asset paths in nested folders

Tags: relative-path, harp

In harpJS, say I have a folder structure like this:

```
mysite/
  - _layout.ejs
  - index.ejs
  + styles/
      - main.css
  + folder-level-1/
      - page-level-1.ejs
      + folder-level-2/
          - page-level-2.ejs
```

In `_layout.ejs` I have a CSS path reference:

```
 <!-- In _layout.ejs -->
 <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It works fine in `index.ejs`, however the path breaks in `page-level-1.ejs` and `page-level-2.ejs`, since it is not relative.

My current solution (which I'm not that satisfied with) is a little script at the top of `_layout.ejs`:

```
<!-- In _layout.ejs -->
<% var pathPrefix = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < current.path.length; i++) {
      pathPrefix += "../";
   };
%>
```

Then I can write the CSS path as:

```
 <!-- In _layout.ejs -->
 <link href="<%- pathPrefix %>styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

> I feel this solution to be a bit hacky. **Is there a better way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be simply solved by referencing an absolute path for /styles/main.css.

```
<!-- In _layout.ejs -->
<link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then no matter which child page is rendered, it will always reference `/styles/main.css` and not `/folder-level-1/styles/main.css`

Comment: There's an issue, however, when deploying the compiled output to a webserver. The root is not always what you'd expect...